# Wordpress: Where to locate the permalink in the database

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Someone from our team change the permalink of a page to http://www.example.com/ so this is now the homepage. My problem is I need to change the homepage, but whenever I create a home.php file it is not executing but rather "that" page.

I tried to change the permalink in the admin panel but it doesn't give me an option to do so. Then I tried to change it in the database but I can't locate it. Also tried changing the id or the guid and change the page_id in the wp_post tables but now whenever I go to the homepage it redirects me to google search result. So I guess deleting the page will have the same result. Lastly I change the post_type attribute to post, but it is still goes to the homepage.

Thanks!

Comment: *"I tried to change the permalink in the admin panel but it doesn't give me an option to do so."* ==> are you an admin? Isn't it displayed under the title of your page? Which version of WP, just in case?

Comment: Yes, i'm an admin and using the latest version 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think someone's made changes to the [reading settings](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) - is `Front page displays` set as `Your latest posts`?

[image: WordPress reading settings paget]

Comment: Looks like this is it. I'll check this out later.